# Calling non-library code from an Android library

Tags: android, reflection, android-library, static-initialization

Since Android introduced library projects, I've been converting my app into a library so that I can make several versions with appropriate tweaks (for example, a free and pro version using the same code base, but changing a few things).

I initially had trouble allowing the library project's code access to fields in my sub-projects. In other words, my free and pro versions each had a class with a few constants in them, which the library project would use to distinguish certain features.

In the sub-project, I extended the library's main activity and added a static initialisation block which uses reflection to change the values of fields in the library.

```
public class MyMainActivityProVersion extends MyMainActivity {

    public static final String TAG = Constants.APP_NAME + "/SubClass";

    static {
        try {
            ConstantsHelper.setConstants(Constants.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "--- Constants not initialised! ---");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

In this code, ConstantsHelper is in the library, and I am providing Constants.class from my sub-project. This initialises the constants in the library project.

My approach works great, except for one particular use case. When the app hasn't been used in a while and it is 'stopped' by the OS, the static fields in ConstantsHelper are forgotten.

The constants are supposed to be reset by the main activity (as shown above), but the main activity isn't even launched because the OS resumes a different activity. The result of this is that the initialisation of the constants is forgotten and I cannot re-initialise them because the resumed activity is in the library (which has no knowledge of the sub-project).

**How can I 'tell' other activities in the library to call code from sub-projects on resuming? Alternatively, is there a way to ensure that some code in my sub-project is called on every resume?**

Comment: I might be able to explain what's happening in terms of the classloaders, but I don't totally understand just yet -- what do you mean that 'the resumed activity in in the library'? It's `MyMainActivityProVersion`, right, which is in your app. And what do you mean by constants being forgotten?

Comment: MyMainActivity goes on to call some other activities, in this case it's ViewerActivity, which resides in the library project. If the user is at ViewerActivity and then presses 'home', the application is eventually shut down and the constants in ConstantsHelper have to be re-initialised. They aren't re-initialised because when the user resumes the app, the resumed activity is ViewerActivity, and my important code above isn't executed

Comment: So the Constants values are not just for the ProVersionActivity? Are you aware of the Application class? It will be created once regardless of the "sub activity" that is started.

Comment: Yes, the constants need to be shared across many of the activities in the library project. I can't use the Application class because it has the exact same issues as my approach: it works while the activities are being paused, but not when the activities are killed by the OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I never found a good answer to this question. I'll probably continue with my terrible use of reflection and figure out some hacky workaround.

I felt I should come back and at least point out that I didn't solve this for the benefit of others who come to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're "cheating" by trying to share data across two Activities through static members. This happens to work when they're in the same, or related, classloaders. Here I believe Android uses separate classloaders for separate Activities, but, child Activities are in child classloaders. So `ViewActivity` happens to be able to see up into the parent classloader and see statics for the parent. Later I believe that parent goes away, and so your child re-loads `MyMainActivity` locally when you next access it and it's not initialized as you wanted. (Well, if it's not that, it's something very like this explanation.)

I think there are some more robust alternatives. You could use the `LicenseChecker` API to decide whether you're in a free or for-pay version rather than rely on details of the activity lifecycle and classloader. That's probably going to be better as it protects you from other types of unauthorized use.

Comment: You may have misunderstood the situation (and I don't blame you, reading a textual explanation is hard). I'm not sharing static members in activities, they are being shared through a constants class in the library which is 'filled in' with useful information by the sub-project's activity. It is then accessible to all the library's activities. However, when the application is killed by the OS, the constants class is 'un-initialised', and there is no way for me to get the library project to 'see' the sub-project and the code within it that fills in those constants. That's my problem

Comment: I may misunderstand, but what you're describing still sounds like you're relying on something related to the class itself, not objects or instances. A class can't "uninitialize" -- however you sure can end up reloading the class again in a new classloader, or finding yourself making a new singleton or something, for the reasons I gave. It still could be a red herring -- would have to see the code -- but hopefully that clarifies whether this idea is relevant or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this using Android resources.
Basically, define your constants in a resources xml values file in your Library project 

 
E.g. "lib project"\values\constants.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <bool name="const_free_version">false</bool>
   <string name="const_a_constant">pippo</bool>
</resources>
```

Then, in your sub-project you can redefine the lib-project values using a different resources xml values file:

E.g. "sub project"\values\constants.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <bool name="const_free_version">true</bool>
</resources>
```

In your lib project code when you refer to R.bool.const_free_version you get the actual value based on sub-project constant values xml.

Note that you don't have to redefine every values defined in the lib project constants.xml but only the ones you need different in your sub project.